# Explaining confusing conditional string format

Tags: c#, formatting, string.format

An ex-coworker wrote this:

```
String.Format("{0:#;;} {1:records;no records;record}", rows, rows - 1);
//Rows is a integer value
```

I read articles like these

[Code Project - Custom String Formatting in .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6533/Custom-String-Formatting-in-NET)
[MSDN - Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx)

But I don't still get it how that format works. Obviously I can see the output but I don't understand this part `{0:#;;}` and the second one. I want to do the same thing for specifying ages (year, years...)

I'm very curious about this string format. Can someone can explain this behavior? The author does not work with us anymore.

Comment: [The `";"` Section Separator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#SectionSeparator)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a [custom numeric format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx), basically - but a pretty odd one, to be honest. In fact, it's two of them:

```
#;;
records;no records;record
```

In each case, you've got three sections, due to having two [section separators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx#SectionSeparator) (the semi-colons):

> The first section applies to positive values, the second section applies to negative values, and the third section applies to zeros.

Your situation is further complicated by the developer using `rows - 1` as the value to be formatted  by the second format string, so it's really:

- `records` if `rows` is greater than 1 (so `rows - 1` is positive)
- `no records` if `rows` is equal to 0 (so `rows - 1` is negative)
- `record` if `rows` is equal to 1 (so `rows - 1` is zero)

And the first format string *only* includes the value of `rows` (due to the `#`) if `rows` is positive. So the overall result is:

```
Rows     Result
   2     2 records  (ditto for other values greater than 1)
   1     1 record
   0     no records
```

Personally I would have either used a conditional operator for that, or if/else statements - using a custom numeric format string is "clever" in the worst way...

Comment: I...wait...what? EDIT...thanks for explaining further

Comment: That a pretty clever usage of string format. It's also important, that only for positive values actual number will be printed (because of `#;;` in first format).

Comment: @CalvinSmith: I've edited it further - this may help.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: Yes, but I'd use the words "pretty clever" in a derogatory sense in this case. This isn't code I'd want to actually see...

Comment: @JonSkeet Thats true, but its also something I havent encountered in string.format and could be useful for certain situations

Comment: Sure. I totally agree. It's kind of abusing the BCL.

Comment: @CalvinSmith: Yes, certain situations like hating your colleagues with a passion ;) I agree it's interesting though.

Comment: I'm tempted to memorise this for when being interviewed they ask if you have any questions; to wipe the smug look off their developers (knowitall) face :D

Comment: see both Paul and John came up with awesome scenarios right away.